# Specifying model in mvabund - is GLMM an option?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm, ecology

I'm looking to use some of the packages in `mvabund` to do a fourth corner analysis and was wondering if I can use glmm within this package. Everything's been laid out around glm, and I haven't been able to find any examples of glmm being used.